# ElasticSearch - Match (email value) returns wrong registers

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using match to search for a specific email but the result is wrong. The match property brings me results similar. If the result exists, the result displays on first lines but when the results not exists, it brings me result by same domain.

Here is my query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "email" : "placplac@xxx.net"
        }
    }
}
```

This email doesn't exist in my base but returning values like banana@**xxx.net**, ronyvon@**xxx.net***, etc.

How can i force to return only if the value is **equal** from the query?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `"index":"not_analyzed"` on the `"email"` field. That way, the only terms that are queried against are the exact values that have been stored to that field (as opposed to the case with the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which is the default used if no analyzer is listed).

To illustrate, I set up a simple mapping with the `email` field not analyzed, and added two simple docs:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "email": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{"email": "placplac@xxx.net"}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{"email": "placplac@nowhere.net"}
```

Now your match query will return only the document that matches the query exactly:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "email" : "placplac@xxx.net"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "email": "placplac@xxx.net"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/12763f63f2a75bf30ff956c25097b5955074508a

**PS:** What you actually probably want here is a [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) or even [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html), since you don't want any analysis on the query text. So maybe something like:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "email": "placplac@xxx.net"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: is possible add it to all index?

Comment: You can set up something like what is shown here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8015, using [copy_to](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to). I wasn't able to make it work using the `"_all"` field.